# How to make a button in html that makes a post request but does not redirect

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, backend

I need to make a button in HTML that makes a POST request to a fast route, passing parameters through req.params. The problem is that I haven't found a way so that when I press the button it doesn't redirect me to the route, but it stays there while it makes the request.

I have this
`

```
<form class="addCart"action="http://localhost:8080" method="post">
    <button type="submit" formaction="/api/carts/products/{{product.id}}"> +1 </button>
</form>
```

`
It works fine and makes the request, but it redirects me to its route and I need it not to be redirected but to stay on the page where I press the button

Comment: dont use a form but use some javascript and the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API.

Comment: `form onsubmit="()=> false"`

Comment: @skara9 That does not work

Comment: @DiegoCast Sorry, try `onsubmit="return false"`

Answer (score 0):

Send post request using javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

On click method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button#using_buttons

Comment: I need to put it all in the html, how would it be exactly using the script tag?